# Dropdown selection on AHK using Chrome.ahk

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, autohotkey

I would like to find out if there is a way to select a dropdown list using https://github.com/G33kDude/Chrome.ahk with AHK codes?

Here's my example codes but I am unable to use to select the option here, *document.getElementsByName(""cars"")[0].options[1].selected=true* works on Google Chrome console though.

```
#Include ../Chrome.ahk

FileCreateDir, ChromeProfile
ChromeInst := new Chrome("ChromeProfile")


PageInst := ChromeInst.GetPage()
PageInst.Call("Page.navigate", {"url": "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select"})
PageInst.WaitForLoad()

PageInst.Evaluate("document.getElementsByName(""cars"")[0].options[1].selected=true")
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out w3schools is not the best example for testing out codes... It actually worked on a normal website with dropdown lists.