# AHK Form automation with Chrome.ahk and JS

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I'm having some issues trying to get this code to work within servicenow as I don't really know Javascript that well.
Basically, I have a GUI I've made in AHK that's using chrome.ahk.
I have chrome loaded properly so chrome.ahk can do what it does. My test says it's opened using the correct port and if I do a js based alert on the page I want to work in, it works just fine.

My problem is that I can't seem to get my code to change the drop down menu i want it to change.

This is the element I'm trying to work with:

```
<select aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="label.new_call.call_type" ng-non-bindable="true" name="new_call.call_type" id="new_call.call_type" onchange="onChange('new_call.call_type', arguments.length === 2 ? arguments[1] : false);" style="; " class="form-control  " choice="1">

<option value="" selected="SELECTED">-- None --</option>
<option value="hang_up">Hang Up</option>
<option value="incident">Incident</option>
<option value="password_unlock">Password/ Unlock</option>`
<option value="Request">Request</option>
<option value="status_call">Status Call</option>
<option value="Store Phone Number">Store Phone Number</option>
<option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
<option value="Vendor Status Call Back">Vendor Tech Call Back</option>
<option value="wrong_number">Wrong Number</option>`
</select>
```

I've tried all sorts of different variations to get this work and I just have no idea what's going on, nothing I do works.

I've scoured google trying every single method I can find and nothing is working.

Here's the last thing I used which didn't throw any errors:

`page.evaluate("document.getElementsByName('Call Type').selectedIndex= '2' ")`

I've also tried getElementsByName('new_call.call_type'), tried it by ID as well. I've tried selecting by value, ID, index, different variations of them depending on what I found in google, nothing is working.

My question is, what -should- work if I wanted to select the value "incident"? It can work with either value or index, either way doesn't matter as long as it works.

I've tried many different variations of

`page.evaluate("document.getElementsByName('Call Type').selectedIndex= '2' ")`

with the GetElement being either ByName or ByID... the name being either Call_type, Call Type, new_call.call_type

I've tried many different variations of .selectedIndex, .selectedValue and different variations with .options

I tried going through this post: [Dropdown selection on AHK using Chrome.ahk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578824/dropdown-selection-on-ahk-using-chrome-ahk)

But I couldn't get that to work either.

Also, I have no control over the code used to produced the form itself, so changing anything within the select element is not possible and I have to work with what is there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps obtain the innerHTML of the parent element and then use ordinary text manipulation (even REGEX would work) to pull out or change the values you need, then post that changed parent with the edited child.

But, by the way, `dots` or "`.`" have a special meaning and need to be escaped:

```
page.evaluate("document.getElementsByID('new_call\.call_type').selectedIndex= '2')
```

Comment: So, i tried escaping the . but it's saying the \ is an illegal character, might have to do with chrome.ahk....

But. I was messing around on jsfiddle and used this:
`document.getElementsByName('new_call\.call_type')[0].options[3].selected=true`

It managed to work, changing the dropdown, but when I plug that into my script (and remove the \ since it won't accept it) it gives an error:

"Cannot read properites of undefined (reading 'options' at <anonymous>:1:53"

if im understanding, I think you may be right that I need to look further up the parent element....